# Why is File.Create needed to be closed?

Tags: c#, .net

The following throws an exception "`The process cannot access the file 'D:\MyDir\First.txt' because it is being used by another process.`"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\MyDir");
    File.Create(@"D:\MyDir\First.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\MyDir\First.txt", "StackOverflow.com");
}
```

However following works:

```
using (File.Create(@"D:\MyDir\First.txt"))
{ 
}
```

or

```
File.Create(@"D:\MyDir\First.txt").Close();
```

Why? What in `File.Create` needs to be closed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File being used by another process after using File.Create()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781357/file-being-used-by-another-process-after-using-file-create)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`File.Create` is doing more than you think here.  It's not just creating the file, it's also returning an active stream to the file.  However, you're not doing anything with that stream.  The `using` block in your latter example closes that stream by disposing it.

Note also that this is a significant clue about the return value:

```
File.Create(@"D:\MyDir\First.txt").Close();
```

(It actually wasn't intuitive to me when I first read your question, but looking back at it this line of code actually says it all.)

Your next step, calling `File.WriteAllText` also does more than you think.  According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx), it:

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file.

So it would seem that your `File.Create` call isn't really needed here anyway.

Comment: +1 For mentioning that it returns a `FileStream` and is redundant.

Answer (score 22):

Because it opens a file stream, which is a class managing some operating system low-level resources and those must be released in order to let other operations in other threads, and even in other applications, access to the file.

Answer (score 11):

You don't actually need to call `File.Create()` to then be able to call `File.WriteAllText()`.

`File.WriteAllText()` will create a new file and write to it then close the file all in one handy method.

If the file already exists it'll be overwritten.

Answer (score 10):

The MSDN docs for [File.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) explain this:

> The FileStream object created by this
>   method has a default FileShare value
>   of None; no other process or code can
>   access the created file until the
>   original file handle is closed.

Basically until the file create is closed the file cannot be access by another process (in this case your attempt to write to it).

Answer (score 8):

`File.Create(string)` returns a FileStream object that holds the file open. Even though you are not keeping a reference to FileStream object in a variable, it still exists. The object is eligable for garbage collection, and when that happens the file will be closed, but there is no predicting when the garbage collection will take place.