# Cannot access to simple file "because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#

I have a simple method in my class EDIDocument used to load a xml :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to load specific target file as template
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filepath">file path</param>
    /// <returns>loading status</returns>
    public bool Load(string filepath)
    {
        //file exists
        bool returnValue = File.Exists(filepath);
        //file is a xml
        returnValue &= Path.GetExtension(filepath).Equals(".xml");
        //if file is valid
        if (returnValue)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filepath);
            //load document
            this._xmldoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            //load complete
            returnValue &= (this._xmldoc != null);
        }
        //End of method
        return returnValue;
    }
```

I have a unit test for this method :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Test success on load xml document
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLoadXML_Success()
    {
        File.Create("xml.xml");
        //create document
        EDIDocument doc = new EDIDocument();
        //load something wrong
        bool result = doc.Load("xml.xml");
        //test
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
```

I have always an exception when i start my unit test :

Test method EDIDocumentTest.TestLoadXML_Success threw exception: 
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:......\Debug\xml.xml' **because it is being used by another process**.

I have googled this issue and i have tried multiple solution with XmlReader, StreamReader... by i have always the same exception...

My question is : what to do into my method Load for to fix this exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`File.Create` returns a stream to the file, so it keeps a handle open to it. You need to close the file first. This should work:

`File.Create("xml.xml").Close();`

See this question for more details: [Why is File.Create needed to be closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072310/why-is-file-create-needed-to-be-closed)

Comment: That's perfect, tanks for the link ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to dispose of the `XmlReader`:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filepath))
{
    //load document
    this._xmldoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    //load complete
    returnValue &= (this._xmldoc != null);
}
```

You also need to change the way you create your file, like this:

```
File.WriteAllText("xml.xml", "");
```

as you never dispose of the filesystem handle used in `File.Create`.

Comment: It was not my solution, but in my case, i think it's better to use your statement with "using( ..."

Answer (score 0):

[**File.Create**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) has a return value. It's a **[FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)**.
That FileStream holds the file.
You need to dispose of that FileStream to get access to the file:

```
FileStream f = File.Create("xml.xml");
f.Dispose();
```

or:

```
using (File.Create("xml.xml")) {}
```

If you don't dispose of it manually, it will be disposed randomly when the GC gets to collect it... But until then it will hold the file.