# IO Exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, io

In my c# application which developed with c# in visual studio 2012 I created a file by this command : 
    `System.IO.File.Create("config.conf");`
after that in the next line I want to use the file by this command : 
    `System.IO.StreamReader rd = new System.IO.StreamReader("config.conf");`
But I get This exception :

> "The process cannot access the file '\config.far' because it is being used by >another process."

I used thread.sleep(2000) to make application wait but still it doesn't answer.

I will appropriate any help.

Comment: The problem here is not the *this* code, but the code that in some way accessed config.confg and left it open

Comment: The problem here **is** in this code. `File.Create` returns an open `FileStream` for the newly created file. Until GC collects (and thus calls the finalizer of) that stream, the file will be left open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is File.Create needed to be closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072310/why-is-file-create-needed-to-be-closed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates the file and *returns a `FileStream` holding the file open*.

You can do this:

```
System.IO.File.Create("config.conf").Dispose();
```

by disposing of the returned stream object, you close the file.

Or you can do this:

```
using (var stream = File.Create("config.conf"))
using (var rd = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    .... rest of your code here
```

Additionally, since disposing of the `StreamReader` will also dispose of the underlying stream, you can reduce this to just:

```
using (var rd = new StreamReader(File.Create("config.conf")))
{
    .... rest of your code here
```

Final question: Why are you opening a newly created stream for reading? It will contain nothing, so there's nothing to read.

Comment: Tss, Lasse, are you copying from me? :-D

Comment: Nope, I was not, but it would've saved me some work so now I will ;)

Comment: I take that as a compliment :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var conf = System.IO.File.Create("config.conf"))
{
    using (var rd = new System.IO.StreamReader(conf))
    {
        // Do whatever you want to do with the file here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a stream to the file. That is: The file is already opened for you!

You could do this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader rd = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.File.Create("config.conf")))
{
   ...
}
```

By the way, this does not really make sense. What do you expect an empty, newly created file to contain?

Answer (score 0):

When working with files, it is always a good idea to dispose of the file once you are done.

This can be done by two different techniques, the most popular one is using a "using" statement:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(fileNamePath))
{
    // insert logic here, for example:
    fileStream.SetLength(fileSize);
}
```

The other one, is calling the .Dispose method.

Answer (score -3):

Close the file if it is opened in notepad or something similar.