# the process can't acces the file using streamwriter

Tags: c#, file

i read the file, when Form loads

```
string line;
if (!File.Exists(dir)) File.Create(dir);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dir);
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{ /* do something */}
reader.Close();
```

then I press the button and write something in this file. but in line

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(dir);
```

i have an error "file used by another process". why? i close my reader..

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781357/file-being-used-by-another-process-after-using-file-create

Comment: The file is open because File.Create() creates a FileStream. Next you create a StreamReader while the FileStream is still open. Other suggestions: Since you are opening a file, change 'dir' to 'file' (proper variable naming). Also... it doesn't hurt to use line breaks.

Comment: Use File.Open. You can set the "mode" to create the file if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.Create` opens the file and returns you `FileStream`. Try:

```
using (var fs = File.Open(dir, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        { /* do something */}
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also do

```
if (!File.Exists(dir)) File.Create(dir).Close();
```

to make sure stream is closed

Comment: your code always create new file. i need to use the file with params. (if i havent file - create)

Comment: Use File.Open and set the mode to create the file if it doesn't exists already

Answer (score 2):

These 2 lines conflict:

```
 if (!File.Exists(dir)) File.Create(dir);
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dir);
```

because File.Create() creates a new file and *keeps it open*. Therefore blocking the opening of the file for the StreamReader.

On the API level, File.Create() does not what you think. It is very different from Directory.Create().

But functionally your code makes no sense either, why would you create  a new file just before reading it?  It will always be empty.

Just use

```
if (File.Exitst(dir))
{
  var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(dir);
  foreach(string line in lines) {  /* do something */ }
}
```

Comment: look carefully !Exists - if file exists, program don't create it

Comment: Yes, I read that. Answer stands. You should never have to Create() it.

Comment: And btw, `dir` is a very bad name for a fileName.