# File.copy delete destination file? is it possible?

Tags: c#

I use a simple code:

```
File.Copy(source, destination, true);
```

To copy a file from a UNC path (source) to a local path (destination). The third parameter makes it that if the file is already there, it will be overwritten.

This works 99%. However, when the source file is locked, I sometimes saw this error:

> The process cannot access the file '\xxxx\aaaa.dll' because it is being used by another process.

Then the destination file still disappeared. I can only think that `File.Copy` first deleted the local file and then when it is trying to copy things over, it failed and throw exception?

It that so, and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried the method from this question? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781357/file-being-used-by-another-process-after-using-file-create

Comment: This is extremely common exception. The problem is what it says. The file is locked by other process.

Comment: What is an `unc` path?

Comment: @jmstoker: Essentially a network path, rather than a local device.

Comment: @jmstoker Universal Naming Convention - Windows-specific

Comment: @daxu: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: I think you should test it by locking the file yourself and seeing if File.Copy deletes it.  Then post the answer.  I am curious to know!  This would be a good thing for Microsoft to specify in the documentation.

Comment: @MobyDisk: All that will tell you is that the locking system works.  Clearly it deleted the file; locking it first will just prevent its deletion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I meant lock the source file.  I thought daxu is asking "Is it possible that File.Copy deleted the file?"  It sounds like it does, and a simple test would verify that.

Comment: @MobyDisk The OP is not describing deletion of the source file, but of the *existing target file having the same name.*  Read the question closely, folks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, I see that.  That is why I propose the test.  He sees the file is deleted, and seems to assume that File.Copy deleted it.  I propose he test it.  If he already saw it do this and knows it, then there is no question.  Merely a statement that file.Copy does this.

Comment: I find this behavior weird. This case is barely documented but internally calls Kernel32's [CopyFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Comparable operations are (not necessarily documented to be) atomically, i.e. only removing the old file after the entire operation successfully completes (copy to temp file, delete target, rename temp to target). Can you create a small code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @MobdyDisk You don't need a lock to tell you that.  All you need is to execute that single line of code (perhaps in the debugger).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: He needs to execute that single line of code, but with the source file locked.  Simply running that line of code with the source file not locked will copy it, and tell him nothing.  Like CodeCaster says, the idea is to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Could not reproduce.

```
File.Create(@"c:\test\source.txt");
File.Create(@"c:\test\target.txt");
var stream = 
    File.Open(@"c:\test\source.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
File.Copy(@"c:\test\source.txt", @"c:\test\target.txt", true);
```

throws the exception, but preserves the target file.

Comment: heh, I was about to post the same code to clarify our discussion.  +1

Comment: Same here, same over SMB/Samba.

Comment: this only happens extremely randomly, also the unc path has dfs enabled on the folder. Will that have any impact?

Answer (score 2):

[ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) showed me the destination file is *not* accessed when the source file throws a sharing violation upon opening.

The code shown does not even touch the destination file when the source file is locked, let alone delete it.

Comment: this only happens extremely randomly, also the unc path (the source) has dfs enabled on the folder. Will that have any impact?

Comment: The copy function does not seem to even bother about the destination file when the source file is not readable. It would be pretty inconsiderate when the destination file would be deleted regardless the source file is readable. Would you expect `Copy("nonexisting", "existing", true)` to remove the existing file? Are you sure the _destination_ file gets deleted by _your program_ when the _source file_ is locked?